# How to create a simple class that holds an array

Tags: objective-c, class

Ok, begginer question here.

I create a class to hold a list of my dvds, h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Films : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *horrorFilms;

- (NSMutableArray*) createListOfHorrorFilms;

@end
```

m file:

```
#import "Films.h"

@implementation Films

- (NSMutableArray*) createListOfHorrorFilms{

    self.horrorFilms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"The Shinning", @"Carrie",@"The Blair Witch Poject", nil];


    return self.horrorFilms;
}


@end
```

Would this work? If not, what is the proper way of doing it? Thanks

Comment: You may want to use a singleton.

Comment: How would I access it from my View Controller? I've tried using Films.horrorFims notation, but that's not correct as it prompts "property not found on object of type" warining. Thanks

Comment: That's because you're attempting to access it as a class property instead of an instance property. Try initializing an instance of "Films" and then you'll be able to access `horrorFilms` on that particular instance.

Comment: @Paul if my answer work for you na then please make it by selecting check, so others could be benefitted

Answer (score 2):

Hi You could prefer plist. if you are using more static values in your class. Which will be easy to modify and handle in future.

For doing the above case in plist.

- Create a plist (Right click Project folder->New File -> resources -> select Property List), Assign a plist name for example horrorFilms.
- horrorFilms plist will be saved in your project folder.
- Select horrorFilms and change root plist type to NSArray from NSDictionary.
- Add Itmes (as String) to your root plist Array

[image]

-Go to Your .m Controller class. Add the following method to fetch plist.

```
 - (NSArray *)horrorFilmsList
{
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"horrorFilms" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray * arrhorrorFilms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
return arrhorrorFilms;
}
```

- 6 fetch your plist array anywhere by [self horrorFilmsList. If you want to see in log try this in viewDidLoad     **NSLog(@"\nHorror Films-->%@",[self horrorFilmsList]);**